# Line integral $\int_L xe^{-y}ds$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a line integral: $\int_{L}xe^{-y}ds$ where:

$x=2\arctan\left(t\right)-t+3$

$y=\log\left(1+t^2\right)$

$t\in [0,1]$

Then of course $\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}=1$ and the integral can be changed into

$\int_0^1\left(2\arctan(t)-t+3\right)e^{-\log\left(1+t^2\right)}dt$.

But this integral looks horrible and I cannot spot any kind of mistake. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your integrand by noting that $e^{-\log(t^2+1)} = \frac{1}{t^2+1}$. From there use the change of variable
$$
y = \arctan(t) \ \ \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ \ dy = \frac{dt}{t^2+1} 
$$
and the answer should follow quite simply. I find that the answer is $\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2} \log(2)$.

Comment: Oh no, it's so obvious. No idea why I haven't seen it myself, probably because it was late. Thanks a lot mate!